# how to get the "id" property of an ndb.Model

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine for the first time and it's quite fun.
I was able to set up my handlers, and start creating / reading models.
The problem I'm facing is that I can't get the "id" field of the model:

```
m = MyModel.get_by_id(someId)
logging.debug(m.key)  // prints: Key('MyModel', 1) for example ... I want the '1'
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `id` like this:

```
m.key.id()
```

Comment: <facepalm>doh</facepalm> thanks Lipis, that's quite intuitive, should have guessed it.

Comment: @just_a_dude not really.. it's hard to guess where to start..:)